# Splitting NLP logic into server and client parts

Tags: java, javascript, applet, nlp

I have to create NLP engine with a website frontend. The user should type a sentence in the editbox and receive an answer after sentence analyzing on a server side. I use PHP, Apache, Linux hosting, PostgreSQL. Text analyzer is made as a C++ application with FastCGI technology. Should I make sentence preprocessing on a client side in order to reduce server load?
I mean tokenizing into words, spell checking. If so, what technologies should I use - Javascript, "invisible" Java applet..? I intentionally don't describe server parameters, because Linux hosting can be changed.

Comment: *""invisible" Java applet.."*  No such thing since update 1.7.0_21.  See [Java 7 Update 21 Security Improvements in Detail](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/04/java-7-update-21-security-improvements.html).

Comment: OK, I've never created Java applets.